# phpmailer doesn't attach large attachments, boundary messed up

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to send two or three attachments via phpMailer.
The mail itself sends perfectly when only text or a small attachment, but when I attach 2 pdf's that are (i think) bigger than 1mb total the mail gets garbled, the boundaries are messed up. The data of the file **is attached** if I look in the source, so that is not the problem.

It occurs when using `mail()` and `isSMTP()`. I've set the limits to >256 mb. The file allready exists on the disk (no post/get), I use the base url (`/home/user/domain/public_html/file.pdf`)

Any ideas? Below example of start of the headers of the mail.

```
--b1_6166a1a8c31cfb63964d1ce6fac035a7
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b2_6166a1a8c31cfb63964d1ce6fac035a7"

--b2_6166a1a8c31cfb63964d1ce6fac035a7
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

edit: The calls `$mailer->AddAttachment(...)` are being done as last calls just before the `send()` function.

Comment: `isSMPT()` or `isSMTP()` ?

Comment: isSMTP of course, typo ;) [fixed]